# how to loop through PHP code and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How do I use the PHP loop through the query instead of putting all the result into an array then looping through the array

The way I use array and loop is like this:

```
<?php $userInfos = $qry->querySelect( SQL CODE HERE );

  foreach($userInfos as $uInfo)
        {
        $fName = $uInfo['fName'];
        $lName = $uInfo['lName'];
        $gender = $uInfo['gender'];
?>

First name is: <? echo $fName; ?> and Last name is <? echo $lName; ?>.

<?php } ?>
```

I wanted to know better insight on how PHP loop through the query is better than array. Please redirect me to some example or possibly with MySQL code included.

How can I convert the above php code to be more efficient if I am pulling millions of record?

Thanks so much!.

Comment: just make sure not building a query with * (all columns) but only the ones you need. Other than that, you need to run the query against the database and let mysql return a php array then loop through that array, as you are already doing with querySelect I guess.

Comment: i just wanted to know, is there any benefit by looping through the query instead of an array that contains all the values?

Comment: @danidee: Yes, there is a benefit. The benefit of a fetch loop is that it requires *less* memory. With the fetch loop, we can process each row as it's retrieved, and then discard it, and reusing that memory for the next row. We only have to hold "one row" in memory at a time. With the fetchAll into an array, that's potentially going to require a bloat load of memory to be allocated, to hold a hugh jass array that contains *every* flipping row, before we even process the first row. (So, no difference if you have an unlimited amount of memory available and it can't be used for anything else.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple loop with mysqli_fetch_row()

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use something other than the **`querySelect`** function (which appears to be returning an array).

Maybe the `$qry` object has some other function that will return you a statement handle you can fetch from, like the normal `mysqli_` and `PDO` interfaces provide.

It looks to me like `$qry` is from a homegrown MySQL library "wrapper" class, which exposes a limited subset of the functions.  If that object doesn't provide a way to get a statement handle, you may need to add the appropriate functions to the object definition, or abandon that and just use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

There's lots of examples of how to do that. With PDO, our first cut (before we add error checking and exception handling) might look something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT t.name FROM really_big_table t";
$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
   echo "<br>Name is: ". htmlentities($row['name']);
}

$sth->close();
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

I do the following:

```
//DB Query getData
$q_getData = "SELECT `stuff`, `moreStuff`, `otherStuff` FROM `table`";
$rsgetData = mysqli_query($DBi, $q_getData) or die(mysqli_error($DBi));
$row_rsgetData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsgetData);
$rows_rsgetData = mysqli_num_rows($rsgetData);

if($rows_rsgetData>0) {
    do {
        echo $row_rsgetData['stuff'] . '&nbsp;' . $row_rsgetData['moreStuff'] . '<br>';
        echo $row_rsgetData['otherStuff'];
    } while ($row_rsgetData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsgetData));
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($rsgetData);
        if($rows > 0) {
            mysqli_data_seek($rsgetData, 0);
            $row_rsgetData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsgetData);
        }
    mysqli_free_result($rsgetData);
};
```

That runs the query and loops through each row until there are no rows left - only if there are rows returned in the first place.  Once it's all finished it frees up the connection.