# How do I get mysqli_fetch_row to return more than one row when I run a database search

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm running a simple database search using a form.  I'm only running the search against one of the tables in the database but I'm only getting one row to run.  If the search comes up with two or more possibilities, it won't display any of them.  How can I get it to display multiple rows when it should?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// If there is a search variable try to search database
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'";

        if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}





}
?>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form action="Index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to loop through PHP code and MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403716/how-to-loop-through-php-code-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` to get an array of rows (an array of associative arrays).

Example:

```
// This will display all the rows returned by your SQL query.
$elements = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($elements as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
    echo "<br/>";
}
```